# Cloud functions: oncall function returns null before running chain of promises

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I created a cloud function to create a firebase auth user and to record user's data into firestore.

**Cloud Function**

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, response) => {
  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    displayName: data.name
  }).then(user => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      email: data.email,
      id: user.uid,
      name: data.name,
      role: data.role
    });
  }).then(() => {
    return { status: true, message: 'User added successfully!' };
  }).catch(error => {
    return { status: false, message: 'Error occurred while creating the user!' };
  })
})
```

**Angular .ts file**

```js
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(user) {
    this.angularFireFunctions.httpsCallable('createUser')(user).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

When I call this function in my angular app using angular/fire it returns null. Also, it takes upto 3 minutes to add user to firestore. What should I modify in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the firebase docs on sending back the result for onCall funtions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0#sending_back_the_result), you should return any asynchronous function. So, add `return` keyword before `admin.auth()...` in the cloud function.